# Checking for WSACONREFUSED on a non blocking socket

Tags: sockets

I finally managed to write an non -blocking socket code for host discovery as per the suggestions provided in the previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203263/using-non-blocking-socket-in-a-port-scanner).The  logic of my discovery code is to establish an socket connection with the host on ports such as 80,139.If the socket connection is successful then the host is present or if the host terminates the session by sending an RST packet then the host is present. By using blocking sockets i was able to check for `WSACONREFUSED` for a `RST` packet from the host but the non blocking sockets always returns 0 even though an RST packet was sent from the host for terminating the session . Is there a way to check for the RST packet in the non-blocking mode ? . The code for the same is below

```
 #ifndef UNICODE
 #define UNICODE
 #endif

 #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

 #include <winsock2.h>
 #include <ws2tcpip.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 // Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
 #pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

 int port[]={80,139}; //port number for scanning 

 int wmain()
 {

    // Initialize Winsock
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int i=0,flag=0;
    char ip[20];
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
    wprintf(L"WSAStartup function failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
    }

    SOCKET socketarray[2];

    sockaddr_in clientService;

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server

    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    socketarray[i]=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    }

    printf("\n Enter the Ip Address : ");
    scanf("%s",ip);

    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(ip);

    u_long iMode=1;

 for(i=0;i<2;i++)
 {
    ioctlsocket(socketarray[i],FIONBIO,&iMode);
 }

     fd_set WriteFDs;
     FD_ZERO(&WriteFDs);
     timeval timer;
     timer.tv_sec=5;
     timer.tv_usec=5000000;

 for(i=0;i<2;i++)
 {        
              FD_SET(socketarray[i],&WriteFDs);
              clientService.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)port[i]);
              connect(socketarray[i], (SOCKADDR *) & clientService, sizeof(clientService));
              iResult=select(0, NULL, &WriteFDs,NULL,&timer);

      if(iResult==SOCKET_ERROR||iResult==0)
      {
         printf("The return value of the function = %d",iResult);
            wprintf(L"\n Select failed for the port number %d with error %d ",port[i], WSAGetLastError());

      }
      else
      {
          printf("\n The return value of the function = %d",iResult);
          wprintf(L"\n Select was success  for the port number %d ",port[i]);
      }
}

 for(i=0;i<2;i++)
 {
    closesocket(socketarray[i]);
 }


 WSACleanup();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you REALLY want to see if an RST packet is sent?  or just if it's disconnected?  For asynchronous connects, when the socket is writeable, you have completed your connect -- either successfully or otherwise.

Comment: I'm trying to find whether a host is available by establishing a connection. And a RST packet or WSACONNREFUSED indicates the availablity of the host as per the link http://www.slashroot.in/what-tcp-ping-and-how-it-used . How to check for WSACONNREFUSED or is there a better way for checking it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing the non-blocking connect, you must select() on the socket until it becomes writable. Then fetch the last socket error via setsockopt(). If there isn't one, you are connected.if there is, see what it was.